# Nothing happens after logging in with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm having a strange and probably very simple issue with Devise. The worst part is I've successfully installed and ran it with another app but can't seem to replicate my steps with this current project.

Here's what happens: I put `before_filter :authenticate_user!` at the top of my controller. When visiting a method in the controller, the sign up form is generated successfully. Unfortunately, after filling out the login form the page seems to refresh and I'm faced with the login form again.

I have no idea what's going on. Any ideas where I should be looking to fix this silly little problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check your model. If you have devise :confirmable but haven't set up your app to send out confirmation emails, the user wouldn't be getting confirmed, so its likely the culprit of your issue.

Comment: Elliot, thanks bud you were 100% right. It works brilliantly now.